# How to plot a data on half of Y axis in log scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib

At final, my son give this asnwer, `y = sqrt(y / 2)`, I think it is right answer, do you think so?
[image]
At last, I found `y = sqrt(h) + log(0.5, 10)` is most near what I need, do you have better idea?
[image]
I found the fomular is still wrong when y = 2, how can I get a better formular for all cases?

The sqrt(y) is the answer, but correction for minY = 0.5, the last is `y = max(sqrt(0.5), sqrt(y) - sqrt(0.5))`.
[image]
`sqrt(y)` will be as below
[image]

I modified as below as minY = 0.5 or exception hanppend! log(y)/2 seems like wrong.

```
y = log(y) / 2
if y < 0.5:
  y = 0.75
```

[image]
I want to show white data on the middle of green bar, how can I calculate the y loc on the Y axis? in normal scale, I can use y / 2, but I am not sure how to do it in log scale, I tried 10 ** (log(y, 10) - log(2, 10)), but it seems not correct.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the height is log(y)/2.

Comment: This is log(m) = log(y) / 2, then m = exp(log(y) / 2)

Comment: Which even simplify to m = sqrt(y)

Comment: This is the real y value corresponding to the half the green bar, I am not sure if it is at this height in the histogram as well. I will try it later.

Comment: @paime Please answer it.